# Laravel auto update a field in the table when current date is more than a specific date in the table

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, sql-update, auto-update

I'm trying to update a specific field in the database table when current date is more than another specific field in the table.

My table "task":

```
id |..... | startDate  | endDate   | status
---|------|------------|-----------|--------
1  |..... | 2019/03/13 | 2019/03/14| Process
```

So, if current datetime > endDate, automatically update status to "Expired" in  real time without any click.

I did create a scheduler in Kernel.php, but nothing is happening. My scheduler:

```
 $schedule->call(function () {
            DB::table('tasks')->whereDate('endDate', '<', date('Y/m/d H:i'))->update(['status', 'Expired']);
        })->everyMinute();
```

My end date value and format:

```
2019/03/12 17:00
```

Thank you in advance

P.S - I'm not using Carbon

Comment: i would suggest doing a check when you retrieve the row(s).
It could create a problem if the status is not process but the end date is reached if you have just sql check it (if that is even possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a scheduler, and run simple command that uses **DB**. You can run that task every few minutes and it will do the job.

```
DB::table('task')->whereDate('endDate', '<', now())->update(['status' => 'expired']);
```

If you do not want to use Carbon, simply change `now()` to `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Remember to add single cron entry to start scheduler.

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: @JonKraja Did you define a cronjob? Take a look (Starting The Scheduler): https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Yes, I have define based on laravel documentation. So, I defined in Kernel.php the schedule like in my question

Comment: @JonKraja I suggest to move code to new Command and test it using artisan. Now you can now simple run it without scheduler. Also check storage/logs if there was any error.

Comment: I have also create a new command file and I have write this query to the handle function, and i did call it to schedule function in the Kernel.php but it is the same, nothing is happening

Comment: @JonKraja What about errors, have you got any? Maybe there i no record in db that should be updated, check that, please. Also you can remove `>> /dev/null` part from your cron entry to check errors there.

Comment: No errors in logs. There are some records to be updated, example 2019/03/13 20:09 (satus = Process), I removed >> /dev/null (I got - Running scheduled command: '/opt/cpanel/ea-php71/root/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' status:change > '/dev/null' 2>&1)

Comment: I would like to thank you because there was a mistake in query update(['status' , 'Expired']), it was supposed to be update(['status' => 'Expired']).

Comment: @JonKraja Sorry for mistake, i fixed it, so the answer is now correct.